# Python Pandas check if string contains only one space

Tags: python, pandas

I got a excel file that have a customer column with customers name but in the same column there is other data. I want to only get  customers name but since they are all different I can't figure out how to capture it. My only solution I though was to get the rows that contains only one space between two string (Fist and Last name). This is my code so far :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

#Dataframe for each data needed
customer = pd.read_excel('rpt_rs_ArrivalsPerMeeting.xls', usecols='B', skiprows=17)
activity = pd.read_excel('rpt_rs_ArrivalsPerMeeting.xls', usecols='M', skiprows=17)
resNumber = pd.read_excel('rpt_rs_ArrivalsPerMeeting.xls', usecols='Q', skiprows=17)
numberOfPeople = pd.read_excel('rpt_rs_ArrivalsPerMeeting.xls', usecols='R', skiprows=17)
timeOfMeeting = pd.read_excel('rpt_rs_ArrivalsPerMeeting.xls', usecols='B', skiprows=15)

#Remove empty data in the lists
customer.dropna(inplace=True)
activity.dropna(inplace=True)
resNumber.dropna(inplace=True)
numberOfPeople.dropna(inplace=True)
timeOfMeeting.dropna(inplace=True)

#Lists of data in determine Colums
customer_list = customer["Customer Name"].tolist()
activity_list = activity["Activity"].tolist()
resNumber_list = resNumber["Res.No."].tolist()
people_list = numberOfPeople["Total Places"].tolist()
timeOfMeeting_list = timeOfMeeting["Virtual Reality Tremblant"].tolist()


print(customer)
```

And this is the output :

```
                                         Customer Name
0                                      Raphaelle Pruja
3                                         Arnauld Soni
6                               Meeting Time: 11:00 AM
8    Ticket Customer Virtual Reality Tremblant/2021...
11                              Meeting Time: 11:10 AM
..                                                 ...
167  Ticket Customer Virtual Reality Tremblant/2021...
169  Ticket Customer Virtual Reality Tremblant/2021...
171  Ticket Customer Virtual Reality Tremblant/2021...
173  Ticket Customer Virtual Reality Tremblant/2021...
177                                      Total Places:

[73 rows x 1 columns]
```

So as you can see there is multiple data on the column...

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `string.count(" ")==1` - not sure how to apply this to pandas, but.

Answer (score 1):

Using a toy `DataFrame` as an example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['John Smith', 'bbla', 'A B']})
```

Then all you have to do is this:

```py
df[df['x'].str.count(' ') == 1]
```

You can actually use an even simpler method:

```py
df.query('x.str.count(" ") == [1]')
```

Comment: Yes that what I needed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just filter your data frame by the condition of `count()` the whitespaces:

```
df[df['Customer Name'].str.count(' ') == 1]
```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer Name':
                    ['Raphaelle Pruja',
                     'Arnauld Soni',
                     'Meeting Time: 11:00 AM',
                     'Ticket Customer Virtual Reality Tremblant/2021...']
                 })

df[df['Customer Name'].str.count(' ') == 1]
```

#### Output

| Customer Name |
| --- |
| Raphaelle Pruja |
| Arnauld Soni |

Comment: Exactly what I needed !! Your the best thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the way your date is formed but if you have a column of full names you can spilt it into two new columns of first and last name like this:

```
# new data frame with split value columns
new = data["Name"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
  
# making separate first name column from new data frame
data["First Name"]= new[0]
  
# making separate last name column from new data frame
data["Last Name"]= new[1]
  
# Dropping old Name columns
data.drop(columns =["Name"], inplace = True)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-split-strings-into-two-list-columns-using-str-split/

Comment: Thanks alot I needed that at the same time!!

Comment: Beware, that will split each string exactly once but your "last name" may contain other spaces so your names will be full of garbage the same way that your original rows are

Comment: even if a name has more than one space it will still spilt it to the first name and the rest